# For search purposes: HTML files or store content in database?

Tags: html, sql, search, full-text-search, search-engine

Is it faster to search your web page content if the content is stored in html files or in a database like SQL?

Comment: what do you mean by search purpose? what kind of search do you want? how many pages do you have? plz detail your problem so that others can help you.

Comment: This isn't really a code-related question, it's just theory. But to answer your question, just search the HTML because either way you're going to have to search the entire document and it would be quicker if you didn't have to connect and retrieve information from the database first.

Comment: This question make no sense. Explain your point.

Comment: sorry for the bad question.  If I wish to create and implement a search box on my site, what are the pros and cons of having all page content of my website stored in separate html files as opposed to a database.  What are the advantages of each way in regards to implementing a full text search on my web site.

Answer (score 2):

depends on how you want to search through it. I would prefer to store it into a database and implement full-text-search.

Comment: would it not be better to use something like 'google custom search' for your web page?

Comment: I don't know, would it, @e-zero? Please read the comments directed at you, below your question.